# The symmetric product of symmetric tensors is commutative

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be an finite-dimensional vector space, let $\alpha$
  be a symmetric $k-$tensor on $V$, and let $\beta$ be a symmetric $l-$tensor on $V$. Define the symmetric product of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be the $\left(k+l\right)$-tensor $\alpha\beta$ defined by $\left(\alpha\beta\right)\left(v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\right)=\frac{1}{\left(k+l\right)!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\alpha\left(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}\right)\beta\left(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}\right)$  for all $v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\in V$.

Show that $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$, that is,

$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\alpha\left(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k)}\right)\beta\left(v_{\sigma(k+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(k+l)}\right)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\beta\left(v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(l)}\right)\alpha\left(v_{\sigma(l+1)},\ldots,v_{\sigma(l+k)}\right)$$.

for all $v_{1},\ldots,v_{k+l}\in V$.

Comment: Note that switching $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in your sum is the same as multiplying $\sigma$ by another permutation. The result follows since that is a bijective operation.